# Updating from .NEt 1.1 to 4.0: Windows forms application Objects and Threads being lost

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, .net-4.0, .net-1.1

I recently migrated a .NET 1.1 Windows forms application to .NET 4.0 Windows forms app.
When I step through the code the application works fine.

However, when I run the application without breakpoints I get a few exceptions which all relate to the application unable to reference UI control objects.

The types of errors I am getting are "cannot access disposed object", "cross-thread operation not valid - control accessed from a thread other than the other than the thread it is created on".
Is there a general fix for these threading\timing errors i.e. some .NET 4.0 configuration setting or is it a case of managing the threads in the code?

Any help would be much appreciated as there is a lot of pressure on me fixing this.
I have being putting delegates in wherever this error has occurred e.g.
Private Delegate Sub ClearGensetStationCombosDelegate()

```
    Private Sub ClearGensetStationCombos()
        If Me.mfrmPlanningBoard.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New ClearGensetStationCombosDelegate(AddressOf ClearGensetStationCombos)
            Me.mfrmPlanningBoard.Invoke(d, New Object() {})
        Else
            Me.mfrmPlanningBoard.cboJumpToGenset.Items.Clear()
            Me.mfrmPlanningBoard.cboJumpToStation.Items.Clear()
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: This is a standard bug in .NET 1.x programs.  So common and so difficult to troubleshoot that starting at .NET 2.0, the framework now checks for this mistake.  You've got some long overdue bugs to fix.  Googling the exception message gives you an easy hundred thousand hits, there's little point in adding another one.

Comment: Hi Hans, Thanks for your reply - can you recommend any tools or quick example fixes?